# Sitecore 10 Forms urlRegexValidator Field validator

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation

I have a field which has `urlRegexValidator`.

In Sitecore 10 I have created a new validation in this path

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/Website Validator`.

```
Paramtere : {"regularExpression":"^(https?:\\/\\/)?((([-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*?[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]{0,253}[a-z0-9])?\\.[a-z]{2,63})|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))(:\\d{1,5})?((\\/|\\?)((%[0-9a-f]{2})|[-\\w\\+\\.\\?\\/@~#&=])*)?$"}.
```

The validation is not happening for the field.
Please let me know if I am missing anything here for validation

Comment: Can you confirm that the type of validator is `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Validation.RegularExpressionValidation,Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc`?

Comment: `Paramtere` doesn't look right

Comment: @Mamtha Did you follow the same? https://madhuanbalagan.com/sitecore-9-forms-custom-validation